# How to return multiple keyvalue pairs in c# using foreach loop?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, key-value

Currently I have written a logic to return multiple key value pairs using for each loop, but it's return just the first key-value pair.
My current code is:

```
 public static string ReturnData(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> abc)
        {
            if (abc != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in abc)
                {
                    return $"{{\"{item.Key}\":\"{item.Value}\"}}";
                 }
            return null;
            }
         }
```

Comment: Change the method return type to `IEnumerable<string>` and add the `yield` keyword before `return` inside the `foreach` loop

Comment: Do away with this method entirely, and use whatever value you supply into `abc` directly wherever you use it

Comment: @CaiusJard how ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Somewhere else you have maybe `var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ ["a"] = "a" };` and you're calling `foreach(string s in ReturnData(dict))` - just do `foreach(string s in dict.Select(kvp => $"{{\"{item.Key}\":\"{item.Value}\"}}"))`

Comment: Or, if you're doing this to serialize Json, just install newtonsoft or systemtextjson and do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)` or `JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [iterator block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) to return a list of items

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReturnData(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> abc)
{
    if (abc != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in abc)
        {
            yield return $"{{\"{item.Key}\":\"{item.Value}\"}}";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) extension:

```
abc.Select(item => $"{{\"{item.Key}\":\"{item.Value}\"}}");
```

If you still want to re-use this code, then re-write `ReturnData` like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReturnData(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> abc)
{
    if (abc != null)
    {
        return abc.Select(item => $"{{\"{item.Key}\":\"{item.Value}\"}}");
    }

    return Enumrable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Note, that `this` turns `ReturnData` into an extension method, which allows to call it this way:

```
abc.ReturnData();
```

Comment: Yea, and use it *instead of* ReturnData, rather than *inside of* ReturnData.. An `$@` string with "" instead of \" might look cleaner